# Strange behaviour while runnning spring boot actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator

I am working with a spring boot app which evolve actuator in the pictures .It evolves the endpoint roles.
Below is my controller part which handle the healthStaus

```
 public ModelAndView healthStatus() {
        ModelAndView view= new ModelAndView();
        final String uri = "http://localhost:8090/actuator";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String response=restTemplate.getForObject(uri,String.class);
       try {
           Object ob=new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, Employee.class); }
           catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
        view.addObject("objects",ob);
        view.setViewName("dashboard");
        return view;
    }
```

while the request handle at this part of code at time of execution it show a strange behaviour .It download a file automatically with the same name of url.[image]

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile, since `ob` isn't visible in `view.addObject("objects",ob);`, because it's declared inside `try`. Why do you read to `Object` at all? You should read to `Employee` instead

Comment: I thing you are getting error in lone  String `response=restTemplate.getForObject(uri,String.class);`

Comment: the issue is not of error /exception..how the outputstream get evolve in the picture that it is downloading the jsp file.I want to know that only

Comment: I doubt that this code is the actual code you are using (judging from the exception). Or are you really trying to parse the JSON returned by the actuator endpoint to be an `Employee`? Also why are you doing it manually, the `RestTemplate` does all that for you, and you shouldn't construct a `RestTemplate` but use the already provided one.